# Профиль пользователя

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте!

После ввода в домен, перестал грузиться профиль пользователя (при этом админский грузится). При логине вылетает

> Служба профилей пользователя препятствует входу в систему, невозможно загрузить профиль пользователя

- Windows 7
- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\` - все ок

Как лечить подскажите пж ?

Comment: @Droff Самый простой способ - посмотрите включена ли учетная запись пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Ну что значит "`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\` - все ок"?

Я решил так: под админом зашел, создал нового юзера, вышел из под админа, зашёл новым юзеров, вышел из гового юзера, снова зашёл админом, скопировал все документы и прочее к новому юзеру, все старые папки и SIDы в реестре погрохал.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если есть домен, то винда тянет профили с домена;
2. Новые пользователи создаются ТОЛЬКО в домене, а не на локальном компе;
3. если, находясь в домене, необходимо за каким-то бесом создать локальную учетку, то перегружаемся, входим под ЛОКАЛЬНЫМ админом этого КОМПА и создаем учетку в обычном порядке;
4. Созданные локально учетки в домен НЕ попадают;
5. Локальные учетки юзеров прекрасно грузятся, если комп ввели в домен: при выборе учетки необходимо указать, что источником учеток является локальный комп- эта функция носит такое название, например, "komp1(этот компьютер)" если хотим войти в домен, то выбираем имя домена, например "MYDOMEN"